# Running custom module on ejabberd

Tags: erlang

I am using ejabberd for the first time and i know that it is used for message passing but i still want to run a program for factorial written in erlang to run on ejabberd server and to see its out on the server too.-module(prog).

```
-export([main/0, loop/1]).

fact(0) -> 1;
fact(N) -> N * fact(N-1). 

loop(N) when is_integer(N), N>=0 -> 
    loop(N-1),
    io:format("~B! = ~B~n",[N,fact(N)]);
loop(_) -> ok.

main() -> loop(16).
```

What steps should I follow? I have already created a beam file for factorial program. Please don't refer me process one site as they have not mentioned clear steps regarding this.

Comment: Please show us what you tried already, and where that failed. Aslo see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't need compile it separetly. Add it to /src and compile

Comment: Yes I have put the beam file in the ebin folder and have added this module in the .yml file under the module segment (module:). Now I want to run my erlang code and see its output on ejabberd server. What steps should I follow now